# Possible to add iis express configuration (windows authentication) to asp.net mvc6 project?

Tags: iis-express, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to setup an asp.net mvc6 application to run with windows authentication when debugging using IISExpress **without having to edit the global iis express configuration file**?

In visual studio 2013, you had the possibility to go to properties on your web application project and edit it from there. The changes resulted in some extra xml in the .csproj file with the information.

However, the .kproj file from asp.net mvc6 projects does not have the configuration listed.

I have tried to add the xml properties from vs2013 to the .kproj file which has had no effect.

Is this not yet implemented?

Comment: did u try to add a web.config in your project root folder and setup the authentication in this file ?

Comment: @agua from mars: doesn't seem to be picking up the configuration file whatsoever.

Comment: So u have to write a middleware I guess

Comment: did you try to put the web.config file in wwwroot folder instead your project root ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on ASP.net 5 / MVC 6 project and select properties.
On the left click on Debug.
At the bottom of the Properties->Debug page
uncheck enable anonymous authentication
check Enable Windows Authentication

In your controllers you'd put something like
   [Authorize(Roles = "Domain\\Group")] 
above the class or action methods

Comment: Aye this is how you do it now. The question was asked during beta2 when this window did not exist yet. I'll mark as answer since this is the answer now! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply add your web.config file to your wwwroot directory with the IIS configurations that you want.

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This works when you deploy the application. I'm asking while developping inside visual studio.

Comment: It works if you are using IIS or IIS Express as type development server for your project.

Comment: `HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error` with `This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level.` with `<windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />` for VS 2015 IIS Express